# Odds of specific scenario after $4$ dice rolls

Tags: probability

I have started studying for a statistics competition but seem to be a bit rusty and unsure about the answer (which I can't check).

*"A fair die is rolled $4$ times. What's the probability of each of the numbers $1, 2$ and $3$ appearing at least once each?"*

I tried thinking that I can get the numbers $1, 2$ and $3$ then a fourth roll providing $6$ different numbers. That would leave me **$6$ possibilities** of getting $1, 2$ and $3$ on the $3$ first rolls, in that order.

Since I don't need the $1,2$ and $3$ necessarily on the $3$ first rolls, I thought they can actually be placed in **$C_{4,3} =4$ "positions" of rolls**.

And also, they can come in $3!=6$ **possible orders**.

Adding all that up equals to ${\rm{6}}{\rm{.4}}{\rm{.6 = 144}}$ possibilities of getting $1, 2$ and $3$ at least once, from a total of ${6^4} = 1296$ different outcomes.

$$P = {{144} \over {1296}} \approx 0.11$$

It is a multiple choice and the answer is one from: $${5 \over {36}},{1 \over {12}},{5 \over {12}},{1 \over {24}}$$

And none of the above is equivalent to 0.11, unfortunately. Can anyone help figuring out which step I got wrong?

Comment: You mean 'A fair die' not, "(A pair of) fair dice"?  Mouse/Mice :: Die/Dice.

Comment: Indeed, Bruce. Got it mixed up when translating from portuguese. thanks for pointing it out, I'm going to edit it

Comment: Well, my Hint/Answer is _my_ second try. I got mixed up reading my native English! I tried again because there seem to be various interpretations.

Answer (score 3):

Brute-forcing:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
123(6)&12(5)3&1(4)23&(3)123\\
\hline
132(6)&13(5)2&1(4)32&(3)132\\
\hline
213(6)&21(5)3&2(4)13&(3)213\\
\hline
231(6)&23(5)1&2(4)31&(3)231\\
\hline
312(6)&31(5)2&3(4)12&(3)312\\
\hline
321(6)&32(5)1&3(4)21&(3)321\\
\hline
3!\cdot 6&3!\cdot 5&3!\cdot 4&3!\cdot 3&108\end{array}$$
Hence, the required probability is:
$$\frac{108}{6^4}=\frac1{12}.$$

Comment: Nice to see a thoughtful fresh approach (+1)

Comment: @BruceET, thank you for recognition. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You're double-counting cases like $1,2,3,3$. You need to find how many of those there are and subtract that, since you've counted each of them twice. That yields one of the solutions offered.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment:**  A simulation is offered as a clue.

Here is a simulation in R of a million 4-roll experiments, using
a die with the six faces marked $\{1,20,300,0,0,0\}$ to simplify the code.
The code finds the sum of the four faces for each experiment.
Satisfactory totals are 321, 322, 341, and 621. For example: 321
means 1, 2, 3, occur exactly once each; 322 means two 1's, a 2, and a 3; etc.

```
set.seed(702);  m = 10^6
die = c(1, 20, 300, 0, 0, 0)
s = replicate(m, sum(sample(die,4,repl=T)) )
mean(s==321 | s==322 | s==341 | s==621)  # symbol | means OR
## 0.083186   # aprx ANSW: probability of one of the four outcomes
mean(s==321); mean(s==322)
## 0.055489   # aprx 2/36: prob of getting 1, 2, 3 each exactly once
## 0.009215   # aprx 1/[3(36)] = 1/108: prob of getting 1 twice & 2, 3 once each

5/36; 1/12; 5/12; 1/24  # suggested answers
## 0.1388889  # 5/36
## 0.08333333 # 1/12
## 0.4166667  # etc
## 0.04166667
```

If you like, you can use the output to see when you have a correct combinatorial argument,
which you should be able to explain.

**Addendum (Combinatorial Argument)** after interaction in Comments:

(a) Probability that only 1, 2, 3 appear (one of them twice):
3 ways to choose which number repeats. ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to place the two numbers that are alike. 2 ways to arrange the two that are different. Result: $3(6)(2)/6^4 = 1/36.$

(b) Probability that 1, 2, 3, each appear only once (along with 4, 5, or 6):
3 ways to choose among 4, 5, and 6. 4! ways to arrange four distinct numbers. Result: $3(4!)/6^4 = 2/36.$

(c) Answer: $1/36 + 2/36 = 3/36 = 1/12 \approx 0.083,$ which is one of the suggested answers and which is consistent with simulation result.

Comment: Bruce, thank you for replying.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you say the satisfactory totals are as you state above, your reading of the question differs from the guys' above, yes?

Comment: My take on this question would be using your logic as well. And although your simulation does return one of the multiple choices presented, I still can't put my finger on where my solution drifts away from the right one.

Comment: I will only speak for myself. My interpretation is that 123x, 1123, 1223, 1233 are all favorable events. By 123x I mean 1234, 1235, etc. Everything on this list is OK in any order:  1123, 3121, .... (Sums as in my simulation do not take account of order.) // Not OK: 1122, 1256, ....// Which one?  My sum `621` means 1233 in some order. I would encode 1235 as `321` because i put 0's on faces  4, 5, 6.

Comment: Please see Addendum to my Answer.

Comment: I did. It's clear now. Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is via the Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion (PIE).

Say the outcome of four rolls has "Property $i$" if there is no roll of $i$, for $i=1,2,3$.  Let $S_j$ be the sum of the probabilities of the outcomes with $j$ of the properties, for $j=1,2,3$.

Then
$$\begin{align}
S_1 &= \binom{3}{1} \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^4 \\
S_2 &= \binom{3}{2} \left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^4 \\
S_3 &= \binom{3}{3} \left( \frac{3}{6} \right)^4 
\end{align}$$

By PIE, the probability that the four rolls have none of the properties, i.e. each number from 1 to 3 appears at least once, is
$$1-S_1 + S_2 - S_3 = \frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score -1):

Let's just count the number of ways it could happen.

If they each appear once each, so the last number is a 4,5,6:

```
* pick if the last number is 4,5,6 (3)

* order everything (4!)
```

If one of them appears twice:

```
* pick which appears twice (3)

* order everything, but unorder the numbers that appear twice (4!/2!)
```

Add those products and then divide by 6^4.